# Is there a way to use Json.Net to deserialize some json which calls a method to add the items to a collection (there is no property setter)

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have a class that has a collection which is `readonly` and has no setter.

Is there a way to de-serialize some json and get it call a method on the instance instead of the property setter?

For example:

```
public class User
{
    private ObservableCollection<Movie> _movies;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ReadOnlyCollection<Movie> FavouriteMovies { get; set; }
    public void AddMovie(Movie movie) { .. }
    //-or-
    public void AddMovies(IEnumerable<Movie> movies){ .. }
}
```

The only way to get things into the `_movies` backing field is via the method `AddMovies`. So when trying to deserialize some valid json which has an array of Movies in the json, it will call `AddMovie` or `AddMovies`...

Comment: Derive a converter from `JsonConverter` and have it build your object calling `AddMovies` as needed. [Here's an example](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) although note that that one is a write-only converter and you want to read, so you'll need to override `ReadJson` rather than `WriteJson`

Comment: I've never tested it, but Json.NET claims to support `IReadOnlyList<T>`.  See http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2013/04/07/json-net-5-0-release-1-net-4-5-biginteger-read-only-collections.  More support here: http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2013/10/14/json-net-5-0-release-7-immutable-collections

Comment: _If you can modify the class_, Json.NET supports [`Serialization Callbacks`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm). Combine that with [`ExtensionData`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeExtensionData.htm)... I think you have a way there.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question  - `_movies` is not `readonly`.  Is that missing from the example?

Comment: If you are talking about the `_movies` field, as long as you add a [`[JsonProperty]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attribute to it, and allocate it in the default constructor (which is necessary since it's readonly), it should serialize automatically.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/jOjKwO

Comment: @dbc - _movies is a private member field. It cannot be available nor do i want it available. If you've noticed i've got a ReadOnlyCollection property which is what I'm trying to deserialize the json data into. (if you've noticed, i had another method which is what I use to populate the member backing field).

Comment: @dbc that .net fiddle is actually pretty good :) Problem I have with that -> that class now has a direct dependency on Json.Net. I don't want to have my library have a dependency on it. It's in _another_ library that does the json stuff?

Comment: @Pure.Krome: Then use a converter as I suggested before. If you look at the example, you'll notice that the `Employee` class isn't decorated with any Json.Net attributes. You could have your data models in one library and provide all the deserialization stuff (with json.net) in another library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ninja update by PK:**
I've [forked the fiddle below](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BEc35z) using a collection of *classes* instead of simple strings, for a more complex example that now works, based on the answer below.

---

Use a `JsonConverter` to do custom conversion of your json. Here's a simple example of how that might work. Given a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private List<string> backingField;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IReadOnlyCollection<string> MyStrings { get; private set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        backingField = new List<string>();
        MyStrings = backingField.AsReadOnly();
    }

    public void AddString(string item)
    {
        backingField.Add(item);
    }
}
```

And JSON like this:

```
{
    "MyStrings": [
        "Foo",
        "Bar"
    ],
    "Name":"My stuff"
}
```

You could create a converter to read that json and call `AddString` to populate the `backingField` like this:

```
public class MyClassConverter : JsonConverter
{

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var obj = new MyClass();    
        var jObj = JObject.Load(reader);
        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(jObj.ToString(), obj);           // populate fields we don't need any special handling for
        var stringsProp = jObj["MyStrings"];
        if (stringsProp != null)
        {
            var strings = stringsProp.ToObject<List<string>>();
            foreach (var s in strings)
            {
                obj.AddString(s);
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(MyClass);
    }
}
```

Now to use it, and keep `MyClass` ignorant of how it get deserialized, you can simply do something like this:

```
var m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(MyClass), new MyClassConverter()) as MyClass;
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2cukM3)

Comment: dude. sir. gentlesoul. I need to buy you some :beer: or :cocktail:'s. You hath done it! I also forked your fiddle, changed it a bit to be a bit more real-worldish and to use a collection of classes. :boom: shit works beautifully! So thank you and have a lovely weekend where ever you happen to be.